# Highlight indentation level in code listings

Tags: listings, highlighting

I try to highlight the indentation level of some code listings to explain indentation behaviour of my language. My language is whitespace sensitive. Indentation indicates block structure similar to Python. An else code block (of an if-else construct) begins after the keyword **else**. Its first statement may follow on the same line. Its beginning indicates the indentation level of the code block.

1. Example with same indentation level of if and else code block:

   [image: first example]
2. Example with different indentation level of if and else code block:

   [image: second example]
3. Example with invalid indentation level (on line 5):

   [image: third example]
4. Example with else block beginning on the line after the **else** keyword:

   [image: fourth example]

How can I highlight my code in the **listings** package (similar to these examples and keeping syntax highlighting)?

Comment: I find those colours more distracting than helpful...

Comment: I wouldn't use it that excessive. I would use less intensive colors and just highlight one or at the maximum two indentation levels. For example just the magenta area of the second example (with another color). Apart from that, I'm open for different highlight options.